# Finding a HTML button element reference (class, tag, etc) for VBA to automatically click?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, element

I'm trying to pull data from one of our companies internal websites which uses HTML. The button i'm trying to click is a CSV button but despite trying different methods, i can't get VBA to find this element.

I can get VBA as far as opening the webpage but i'm very clueless about HTML as I've always used other datapull methods,

I've tried usig .getElementsByClassName but i receive an object doesn't support this method.

Using getElementsById allows me to pass by this but objElement then doesn't support .Click

```
Sub OpenIE()

Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim objElement As HTMLObjectElement

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "internal website link"
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    Set HTMLDoc = .document
    Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("btn btn-default buttons-csv buttons-html5")
    objElement.Click


    .Quit
End With

Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

HTML button code:

```
<a class=" "btn btn-default buttons-csv buttons-html5"  tabindex="0" aria-controls="inboundTransfersTable" href="#"><span>CSV</span></a>
```

The end result is to allow the CSV to open as a new excel workbook/sheet as from there i'm very familiar with sorting/filtering data.

Apologies for the spaghetti code as i've had to pathwork found code on other threads due to lack of knowledge

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You are using `.getElementById` but the value you have specified is not the ID for the element (presuming that the html code you provided is complete and correct because the way it is now, seems that it should throw an error?)

Comment: I do get an error throw at objElement.Click which is "Object Variable or With block block variable not set". From my testing so far, i can't get anything to support the .Click method. I have also tried getElementsByTag which throws errors on the Set line

Comment: That could be because `Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("btn btn-default buttons-csv buttons-html5")`did not return an object to be set to `objElement`. So when you ask to click (`objElement.Click`), it has no object to click on

Comment: This is certainly not spaghetti code and is far better than many webscraping posts I see. + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a single class in a css selector

```
HTMLDoc.querySelector(".buttons-csv").click
```

This

```
btn btn-default buttons-csv buttons-html5
```

is a compound class with each space representing the start of a new class name. It may be possible to match just on one class (preferred). I went for the likely option of `buttons-csv`. You can simply join classes with "." inside the selector to add more classes to the selector e.g.

```
.btn.btn-default
```

That has two classes in the selector.

---

Timed loop to ensure element present:

```
Dim t As Date, ele As Object
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

t = Timer
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = HTMLDoc.querySelector(".buttons-csv")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
Loop While ele Is Nothing

If Not ele Is Nothing Then
    ele.Click
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know! I appended my code with `Set objElement = HTMLDoc.querySelector("buttons-csv")
    With objElement
    .Click
    End With` but unfortunately objElement still shows as nothing. i did try other variants such as .btn and .btn-default it still throws an error at .Click due to a null value i guess

Comment: There should be a dot before buttons

Comment: If you do HTMLDoc.querySelector(".buttons-csv").click   what error message do you get?

Comment: i'm currently still getting an "Object variable not set" error after including the dot,

Comment: Ok.. so what happens if you put a delay before that line of Application.Wait Now + Timeserial(0,0,3)

Comment: That's exactly what was needed, i never considered it would need delayed as it waits ti;l the page is loaded but it now works 100% perfect, Thanks very much for the help! I've been trying to pull this for well over a week! i'll definitely be giving you the upvote when i hit 15 rep =D

Comment: I have added a timed loop which is better than an explicit wait.